# Rust tokio_tls - Error accepting connection

Tags: rust, openssl, rust-tokio

I am trying to use the tokio_tls crate for ssl connections.

During the accept phase i got "SSL protocol error" with error code -9800.

this is the code : 
`let tls_stream = tls.accept(stream).await.expect("ssl accept error");`

and thats the output:
`tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'ssl accept error: Error { code: -9800, message: "SSL protocol error" }'`

i wasn't able to find the error-msg or the error-code in tokio-tls, native-tls and openssl crates.

thanks , 
eyal

Comment: The error you received is from [here](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.28/openssl/ssl/struct.Error.html) if you go further there you have a [code error](https://docs.rs/openssl/0.10.28/src/openssl/ssl/error.rs.html#14). So this go into FFI this is way you couldn't find it

Comment: You can also provide you operation system. It can matter in this case

Comment: thanks @S.R ! , it's helpfull , actually i find the bug in the other side of the connection  (non-rust code)- but I think that your comment could be still useful for others .